# Dynamic sidebar nav with current page highlighting

Tags: css, loop, menus

My sidebar loops through all of the child pages based on the parent page. For example, if you're in the "About" section you'll only see "About" child pages in the sidebar.

My problem is that I have no way of highlighting the current page. For example, if you're on the child page "Our Team" (under "About") I'd like to give the sidebar "Our Team" a tag link a "current-page" class.

Is there a way to add a "current-page" class dynamically to the child page you're on?

```
<?php 
if ( $post->post_parent == '4' ) {
    query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=4&orderby=menu_order&order=asc"); 
} elseif ( $post->post_parent == '6' ) {
    query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=6&orderby=menu_order&order=asc");
} elseif ( $post->post_parent == '8' ) {
    query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=8&orderby=menu_order&order=asc"); 
} elseif ( $post->post_parent == '10' ) {
    query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=10&orderby=menu_order&order=asc"); 
}
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
...
```

Comment: Why not use wp_list_pages?

Comment: I don't understand how that would add the highlighting class.

Comment: It ads current class and you can style based on that. And if that'd not enough it has a filter

Comment: Here's the answer: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query_posts-add-class-current-page-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are have a hard time on this so here:

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $curent_post = $post;
    $curent_post_id = $post->ID
    $parents = array('4','6','8','10');
    if (in_array($post->post_parent,$parents)){
        query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=".$post->post_parent."&orderby=menu_order&order=asc"); 
    }
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); 
    if ($curent_post_id = $post->ID){
        echo ' class="highlight"';
    }
    ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

and at the end of your loop add

```
wp_reset_query();
$post = $curent_post;
```

no after that i would like to say that you really should use WP_Query instead of query_posts any time that its not the main query in the page.

and when I'll get back I will post and example using wp_list_pages()